# Find what values were changed to after normalization

Tags: r

How can I see the original values post normalization? Or change them in the final output?

I want to change my final output back to there original values. Or at least close to it considering I aggregate and take the mean.

I have a dataset that has 10 columns and 5,000 rows. After cleaning up the data and selecting which columns and rows I want, I run a normalization code.

Then I run a kmeans and get my output. How can I see what the values were changed to after normalization? Like, if I have Region 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. And post normalization it changes to 0.00, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1. is there a way to change them back to the original in the kmeans output?

I want to change my final output back to there original values. Or at least close to it considering I aggregate and take the mean.

```
       normalize = function(X) {
                 return(abs((X-min(X)))/(max(X)-min(X)))
                 }

       df_age_norm = as.data.frame(lapply(df_age,normalize))

       clusters = kmeans(df_age_norm, 9)[['cluster']]

       df_age_norm$clusters = clusters

       df_age_norm =  
              aggregate(df_age_norm[,1:4],list(df_age_norm$clusters),FUN 
                = mean)
```

I want to change my final output back to there original values. Or at least close to it considering I aggregate and take the mean.

Head of dataset before normalization

```
Age  HHIncome Region MaritalStatus group
18    11000      5             0     1
18    11000      5             1     1
18    12000      2             0     1
18    12000      4             0     1
18    13000      1             0     1
```

Head of dataset after normalization

```
Age    HHIncome Region MaritalStatus group    
0 0.001879699   1.00             0     0    
0 0.001879699   1.00             1     0    
0 0.002819549   0.25             0     0    
0 0.002819549   0.75             0     0    
0 0.003759398   0.00             0     0
```

Comment: i added data examples in the edit for before and after the normalization. Sorry, i had trouble getting the columns to line up.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is inspired in base R function `scale`, that centers and scales the vector by subtracting the mean value and dividing by the standard deviation of the vector `x`. These two values, `mean(x)` and `sd(x)` are returned as `attributes`.

```
x <- -4:5
y <- scale(x)
attributes(y)
#$dim
#[1] 10  1
#
#$`scaled:center`
#[1] 0.5
#
#$`scaled:scale`
#[1] 3.02765
```

I have, therefore, rewritten function `normalize` to also set and return `min(x)` and `max(x)` as attributes. They will be used to later denormalize.

```
normalize <- function(X, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if(na.rm) X <- X[!is.na(X)]
  Min <- min(X)
  Max <- max(X)
  Y <- X - Min
  if(Min != Max) Y <- Y/(Max - Min)
  attr(Y, "scaled:min") <- Min
  attr(Y, "scaled:max") <- Max
  Y
}

denormalize <- function(X){
  Min <- attr(X, "scaled:min")
  Max <- attr(X, "scaled:max")
  attr(X, "scaled:min") <- NULL
  attr(X, "scaled:max") <- NULL
  Y <- if(Min != Max) X*(Max - Min) else X
  Y <- Y + Min
  Y
}


df_age_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(df_age, normalize))

df_age_2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df_age_norm, denormalize))

df_age_2 
#  Age HHIncome Region MaritalStatus group
#1  18    11000      5             0     1
#2  18    11000      5             1     1
#3  18    12000      2             0     1
#4  18    12000      4             0     1
#5  18    13000      1             0     1
```

**Data.**

```
df_age <- read.table(text = "
Age  HHIncome Region MaritalStatus group
18    11000      5             0     1
18    11000      5             1     1
18    12000      2             0     1
18    12000      4             0     1
18    13000      1             0     1
", header = TRUE)
```